# Trying to query data using select statement getting "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" error

Tags: oracle11g

Trying to query data using select statement getting "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" error

Query used:

select userkey, name, value, datatype, position from tableA where key = :1  and userkey in (select * from table(:2 )) and productkey = :3  and name in (select * from table(:4 ));

where values for table(:2) will be like 1,2,3,4,5,6,... (set of numbers)
where values for table(:4) will be like abhcd,bcdeff,hjgsdj,ndfkbhe,..... (Set of varchar's)

I am just wondering if anyone can help in constructing a SQL to query such data.

Comment: Where did you learn that syntax? What happens when you run `select * from table(:2)`? (Never mind the rest!) Obviously, if this subquery is invalid, the full query is invalid as well.

Comment: Hi mathguy, this is not a syntax which i written, this come for our application rest call, so i am trying to run this query manually to gather some performance metrics.

Comment: Also table(:2) & table(:4) are list of values of column's "userkey" & "name" from same table "tableA".